# Remove string with () Python

Tags: python, regex, string

How i can remove all strings in () from list

exaple:

```
['PASSAT (3B3)', 'PASSAT Variant (3B6)']
```

i wont print only

```
['PASSAT', 'PASSAT Variant']
```

Comment: well what did you tried so far ?

Comment: Do you want to remove all `()` or do you want to remove the space before the parentheses as well?